# ServiceBus QueueClient and TopicClient object resue

Tags: c#, azure

I'm writing an Azure function using Visual Studio (multi-layers project), where I'm managing all Azure ServiceBus related code in one class.

([follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205979/servicebus-queueclient-and-topicclient-object-resue))

```
public class MessageBroker : IMessageBroker, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IAppConfiguration appConfiguration;
    private TopicClient topicClient;
    private QueueClient queueClient;

    public MessageBroker(IAppConfiguration appConfiguration)
    {
        this.appConfiguration = appConfiguration;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToQueueAsync(string queueName, string message)
    {
        this.queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(appConfiguration.BrokerConnectionString, queueName);
        BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
        await queueClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToTopicAsync(string topicName, string message)
    {
        this.topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(appConfiguration.BrokerConnectionString, topicName);
        BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
        await topicClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.queueClient.Close();
        this.topicClient.Close();
    }
}
```

I use the `[Inject]` attribute to use DI in the Azure function. Whenever I need to send any message into a queue or topic, I inject `IMessageBroker` and call thr `SendMessageToQueueAsync` method. I see a Microsoft recommendation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements) to reuse `QueueClient` and `TopicClient`.

`IMessageBroker` is Singleton in my DI configuration.

Will the `QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString` method create a new object every time or reuse a connection internally based on the same `ConnectionString` or queuename?

Is there anything I can do better on this code?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead.

Comment: _Will the QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString method create a new object every time or reuse a connection internally based on the same ConnectionString or queuename?_ - I this this question is rather for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `topicClient` and `queueClient` as class fields is unnecessary here, and potentially leads to exception scenarios.

For example, if you were to create a new `MessageBroker` and immediately call `Dispose()` without first calling both the other methods then a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown as `topicClient` and `queueClient` are only defined within these methods.

An alternative could be to make use of the `using` syntax to instantiate a client and dispose of it when done. e.g.

```
using(var topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(appConfiguration.BrokerConnectionString, topicName))
{
    BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
    await topicClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
}
```

Using this approach would allow you to remove the `IDisposable` implementation.

If you want to be able to re-use the same `topicClient` and `queueClient` then you could have a `MessageBroker` for a specific `queueName` and/or `topicName`, and define the clients from the constructor.
(Creating new `MessageBrokers` as necessary for new queue and topic names.)

```
public class MessageBroker : IMessageBroker, IDisposable
{
    private readonly TopicClient topicClient;
    private readonly QueueClient queueClient;

    public MessageBroker(IAppConfiguration appConfiguration, string queueName, string topicName)
    {
        this.queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(appConfiguration.BrokerConnectionString, queueName);
        this.topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(appConfiguration.BrokerConnectionString, topicName);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToQueueAsync(string message)
    {
        BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
        await queueClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToTopicAsync(string message)
    {
        BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
        await topicClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.queueClient.Close();
        this.topicClient.Close();
    }
}
```

If you have need of only one `MessageBroker` (i.e. one `topicName` and `queueName`) then this will be sufficient, and an instance of this can be registered within your DI.

Otherwise, you will need some sort of `MessageBrokerFactory` which can be used to create a `MessageBroker` for a given queue/topic name, that can then be re-used.

```
public MessageBrokerFactory {
    private readonly IAppConfiguration appConfiguration;

    public MessageBrokerFactory(IAppConfiguration appConfiguration)
    {
        this.appConfiguration = appConfiguration;
    }

    public IMessageBroker Create(string queueName, string topicName)
    {
        return new MessageBroker(
            this.appConfiguration,
            queueName,
            topicName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I agreed most of your comments. Since I have multiple queue and topic and sending thousands message in a day. I updated my code based on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008542/4140278.